# Use androidx.* artifacts option is disable in Android Studio when create new project

Tags: android-studio

When I create new project with Android Studio 3.4.1, can NOT uncheck "Use androidx.* artifacts".

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Uncheck Android 9.+(Q) under SDK Manager-> Apperance & Behavior-> System Setting-> Android SDK-> SDK Platforms

Answer (score 1):

delete the android-29 folder from AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms it works for me

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall Android 9.+(Q) under SDK Manager -> Apperance & Behavior -> System Setting -> Android SDK -> SDK Platforms.

As well as delete android-29 folder from C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms

Restart and Invalidate Android Studio.